# Force C# asp.net Webforms website to Desktop View

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, webforms

I have a webforms c# project. When browsing on Android devices it automatically resizes the page incorrectly. I have fixed this using the meta View port tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=1280px, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5"/>
```

I was wondering if I can force the browser to render the page as a desktop version. If I remove the viewport tag the browser resizes the page as it sees fit. MVC projects have a browseroveride feature as below. How can I achieve the same result in a webforms project so the page is always displayed as the desktop version. is there an equivalent? You see I always want to display Desktop version.

```
      Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Desktop);
```

Comment: Using the Chrome DevTools and device emulator, my C# asp.net app went into mobile mode, but I was never able to re-create it. Perhaps someone with more experience in DevTools could provide instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue as well even after removing my ViewSwitcher and Site.Mobile.Master. What solved it for me was going into the RouteConfig.cs file and removing the AutoRedirectMode line:

```
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the viewport settings alone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Look at Responsive Web Design (RWD) CSS Framework [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) V3.0.

Check out the following tutorial:

[Twitter Bootstrap with ASP.NET](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net)

If you always want to display as desktop at all times, take a look at this:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1887521.aspx?How+to+force+a+responsive+design+to+Desktop+viewport+mode](http://forums.asp.net/t/1887521.aspx?How%20to%20force%20a%20responsive%20design%20to%20Desktop%20viewport%20mode)

Comment: tried this (hiding viewport) but it doesn't work. Android automatically resizes it and the website is not in desktop mode

Comment: The reason I'm suggesting Bootstrap is that you have total control over what is rendered by using the CSS media queries... you can easily disable these for different resolutions. It will also give you more consistency across all devices. If this is an old project that you are maintaining then I understand why you're trying this approach - try this? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: You can also disable scrolling: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

Answer (score 0):

Open File ViewSwitcer.ascx

Add this script in div id="viewSwitcher".

```
<script>
   window.location.href = '<%: SwitchUrl %>';
</script>
```